# Finding condition for equal roots

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, roots, real-numbers

I actually stumbled upon this question as a misprint in a Mathematics Problem book by Prilepko.

The original question was to find the values of $a$ for which the equation $x^2+2a\sqrt{a^2-3x}+4=0$ will have equal roots. The misprint was in the placement of $x$, which had to be outside the square root and then, by putting the discriminant of the quadratic equation to be zero, I could find the values of $a$ and the answer matched.

But I was wondering whether it was possible to solve the original question (i.e. without the misprint). Let's say the task was to find the values of $a$ for which the equation above had, say, -

(i) 2 equal roots
(ii) 4 equal roots

Would there be any way to do this problem? I would be glad to know if any numerical technique could be used in this case, although all other types of answers are also welcome.

PS - Even if there would be no such value of $a$ where we can have equal roots, I would like to have a proof/argument for the same, if possible.

Comment: on which side can we find this equation?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner - I don't think I understood what you said. But in case you meant to ask from where did I get that equation, it was just a misprint in a book. I was wondering if we can solve the original problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, if I understand correctly, you already know the solution for $x^2+2ax\sqrt{a^2-3}+4=0$, and you want to solve
$$x^2+2a\sqrt{a^2-3x}+4=0$$
Then first get rid of the square root
$$2a\sqrt{a^2-3x}=-4-x^2$$
$$4a^2(a^2-3x)=(-4-x^2)^2$$
$$4a^2(a^2-3x)-(-4-x^2)^2=0$$
This is a quartic polynomial, so calculating its roots is difficult, but to know if at least two of its roots are equal all we need is its [discriminant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolynomialDiscriminant.html) (this works for polynomials of arbitrary degree)
$$-16384 a^{12}-1157888 a^8+2359296 a^4=0$$
this is a third-degree polynomial in $a^4$, which we can solve
$$a^4=0$$
or
$$a^4=\frac{1}{128} \left(-4523\pm 485 \sqrt{97}\right)$$
$a^4=0$ is not a valid solution for the original equation, but $a=\left(\frac{1}{128} \left(-4523-485 \sqrt{97}\right)\right)^{\frac{1}{4}}$ does make two (imaginary) roots equal, and $a=-\left(\frac{1}{128} \left(-4523+485 \sqrt{97}\right)\right)^{\frac{1}{4}}$ makes it have two equal real roots.

Comment: But the condition $a^4=0$, which is basically $a=0$, does not give me equal roots. As for $a=0$ and negative values of x, I will have $x^2+4=0$, which gives me two unequal imaginary roots. Isn't it?

Comment: Could you also specify (if possible) whether these values of $a$ give us all  4 roots equal, or just 2 roots equal? Or do I have to calculate that explicitly?

Comment: You are right, this answer skips the critical step of verifying that the answer is valid for the original equation. Because we squared in the beginning, some information is lost. It does look like $a=\left(\frac{1}{128} \left(-4523-485 \sqrt{97}\right)\right)^{\frac{1}{4}}$ gives rise to two equal (imaginary) roots $x\approx 3.39566 i$.